# Dict: sort by multiple keys + descending/ascending

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have a dict with keys as str and values as `np.array`. The types of the np.array can also be of type `np.str_`.

```
data = {"col1": np.array((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)),
        "col2": np.array(list("abcdeabcd")),
        "col3": np.array((10, 11, 9, 8, 7, 2, 12, 100, 1))}
```

How can I sort by multiple keys and ascending/descending order similar to what I could do with `pandas`'s `sort_values` method:

**Pandas solution (not needed)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(by=["col1", "col2"], ascending=[True, True])
```

**Numpy or base python solution needed:**

I don't want to use pandas but ideally something in `numpy`. I know that I can use `np.lexsort` to sort by multiple columns. But this does not give me (i) the option to do ascending/descending.

This is the output I want when sorting by col1 and then col2 in ascending / ascending order:

```
{'col1': np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]),
 'col2': np.array(['a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e']),
 'col3': np.array([10, 1, 11, 100, 12, 9, 2, 8, 7])}
```

This is the output I want when sorting by col1 and then col2 in ascending / descending order:

```
{'col1': np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]),
 'col2': np.array(['d', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'e']),
 'col3': np.array([1, 10, 100, 11, 9, 12, 8, 2, 7])}
```

Comment: As long as the arrays are separate values in the dict, you can't use lexsort..  `pandas` turns the dict into a dataframe.

Comment: @hpaulj. Why not `list(dict.values())` and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to sort columns backwards by negating the sort key. Remember that you don't need to pass the actual array to `lexsort`. For signed numerical arrays, you can sort in reverse by negating the values. For unsigned integers, you can subtract the values from the maximum. Strings can either be treated as numbers of you can make a lookup table of signed integers based on [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

Here is a small example of arrays:

```
np.random.seed(0xBEEF)
a = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], 10)
b = np.random.choice([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 10)
c = np.random.choice(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.uint8), 10)
d = np.random.choice(list('abc'), 10)
```

The sort keys in ascending order can be the arrays themselves in all cases. In descending order, we can obviously use `-a` and `-b`. As it happens, `-c` also works:

```
>>> c
array([3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8)
>>> -c
array([253, 255, 255, 253, 254, 254, 255, 255, 254, 253]
```

This may be dependent on the platform representation, but on most popular systems, negative numbers are represented in two's complement form and this should work just fine. If you wanted to be really safe, you could add a check like

```
if np.issubdtype(c.dtype, np.unsignedinteger):
    key = np.iinfo(c.dtype).max + 1 - c
```

And of course we have `d`:

```
>>> d
array(['c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
>>> -d
...
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'negative' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U1') -> dtype('<U1')
```

One way to construct a sort key here is:

```
lookup, key = np.unique(d, return_inverse=True)
```

The elements of `key` are indices into `lookup`, which is in sorted order, meaning that if you sorted `key`, the result of `lookup[key]` would be correctly sorted as well. This means that `key.argsort()` and `d.argsort()` are the same, with the added advantage that you can negate `key`.

In fact, you can take a shortcut an write your key generator using this technique alone:

```
def make_key(arr, asc=True):
    _, key = np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)
    if not asc:
        key = np.negative(key, out=key) # Don't bother making a second array
    return key
```

So your full example could look something like this:

```
def custom_lexsort(arrs, asc=True):
    """
    Lexsort a collection of arrays in ascending or descending order.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arrs : sequence[array-like]
        Sequence of arrays to sort.
    asc : array-like[bool]
        Sequence of True for ascending elements of `keys`,
        False for descending. Must broadcast to `(len(arrs),)`.
    """
    def make_key(a, asc):
        if np.issubdtype(a.dtype, np.number):
            key = a
        else:
            _, key = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
        if asc:
            return key
        elif np.issubdtype(key.dtype, np.unsignedinteger):
            return np.iinfo(key.dtype).max + 1 - key
        else:
            return -key

    n = len(arrs)
    asc = np.broadcast_to(asc, n)
    keys = [make_key(*x) for x in zip(arrs, asc)]
    return np.lexsort(keys[::-1])
```

```
data = {"col1": np.array((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)),
        "col2": np.array(list("abcdeabcd")),
        "col3": np.array((10, 11, 9, 8, 7, 2, 12, 100, 1))}

idx = custom_lexsort(list(data.values()), [True, False, True])
result = {k: v[idx] for k, v in data.items()}
```

I've taken the liberty of reversing the order of the arrays, since `lexsort` sorts from last to first. And sure enough:

```
>>> result
{'col1': array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]),
 'col2': array(['d', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'e'], dtype='<U1'),
 'col3': array([  1,  10, 100,  11,   9,  12,   8,   2,   7])}
```

I've included the third column for sorting because it does no harm. Here is an example of the arrays sorted in place, with only the first two used for sorting:

```
idx = custom_lexsort([data['col1'], data['col2']], [True, False])
for v in data.values():
    v[:] = v[idx]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you provide me with a small example / hint how I could do this. I really don't know how to deal with strings.

Comment: @FredMaster. Will do shortly. It's non trivial until you've been introduced to the tools

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to your example!

Comment: @FredMaster. I've written it up

Comment: incredible. Thank you very much for the solution and the explanations. I learned a lot! It's exactly what I needed.